# Value changes from tuple to integer when returning value between scripts

Tags: python, integer, subprocess, tuples

When I return an `(r,g,b)` value from `script.py` to the running python script the value changes from a tuple type in script.py to an integer type in the runningscript.py.  Why is this, and how can I change the integer in the runningscript.py to a tuple?  I'm using `subprocess.call()` to return the value to the running script and am running python 3.4 on windows 10 computer. Thanks.

from running script

```
color=subprocess.call('color_picker_v1.py',shell='True')
print(color)
color2=subprocess.call('color_picker_v1.py',shell='True')
print(color2)
new_im=ImageOps.colorize(im,color,color2)
```

integer type error returned

from color_picker_v1.py(script.py above)
color is returned as a tuple from a dictionary of colors

Comment: Can you include the relevant bits of code. My understanding is you're calling one python script from another via `subprocess.call()`.

Comment: unless you provide a code sample no one can really help you, but maybe it is worth a shot to: use a numpy array in both cases and just return them. Furthermore, why are you using a script instead of simple functions you can call?

Comment: color=subprocess.call('color_picker_v1.py',shell='True')
print(color)
color2=subprocess.call('color_picker_v1.py',shell='True')
print(color2)               color_picker_v1.py returns tuple when run on it's own and returns an integer on running script

Comment: You can't return a tuple from a called program. The return code is 1 byte (depending on the system). Can you write a very simple example of how your program works? A few lines for each script should do it. Then we can see what you do and how to fix it.

Comment: Please edit your code into the question itself so we can see it formatted properly.

Comment: You say _color is returned as a tuple_ - that's the code we need to see. How do you return it?

Comment: I wrote a test program that pickles an example tuple and writes it to stdout in 6 lines of code. How hard is it to just post a simple example of what you are doing? It doesn't have to be a real r,g,b value, just a hacked up canned tuple and enough supporting code to show us what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` returns a single integer/byte representing the success of the subprocess, not an object (such as a tuple) returned by a function. (see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).

What you probably want to do is to `import` functions, rather than calling another script. See for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Modules#Making_a_program_usable_as_a_module.

If you're sure you want to use `subprocess` you want to learn about `stdin`. Just because it prints a value to the terminal/screen, doesn't mean that's what the program returns.

Comment: I've tried importing my own modules, in a few different ways ,but [None] is always returned to the running script even when I get a tuple of the (r,g,b) values when running the called script.

Comment: Are you importing functions, and then running those imported functions in your 'running' script? That's the way you want to do this. Just importing a script probably isn't what you want to do, that'll just run any code that's not wrapped in a function, but not return anything. Try to separate in your mind the concepts of what's printed to the screen and what's returned by a function. If you try to understand what `if __name__ == '__main__'` does (and why it exists) then I think you'll understand what's going on here.

Comment: I tried importing as a function but the problem may be that this function runs through multiple other functions(color shade choices) before returning the tuple from a dictionary.  I have the if__name__=='__main__'  statement at the bottom so I can run this script alone to verify what is being returned.  I'm guessing I either need to figure out how to rewrite this script so that the return statement is included in the imported function, or figure out how to convert the integer received when performing the subprocess call() on the entire script.

Comment: Going via the subprocess return value is asking for a world of pain, I really don't recommend that. `stdin` is how you access whatever's printed to the screen when you run a command-line program, if you want to continue with the subprocess route. The name/main thing is to /stop/ code running if you're importing it, not to make sure it runs from the command line (it'll do that anyway). And yes, you definitely need the return command included in the imported function, but it running other functions shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  I've been convinced to rewrite the code I wish to import - and make sure that the return command is in the imported funtion.

Comment: Cool, that should work. In general, writing code in functions as opposed to just a list of this-then-that will help you in the long run. If this answers your question could you mark it accepted?